# How do I create a separate account in Smash for Wii U?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

On our Wii U, my wife and I have separate Miis. For all the other games we've played, this gives us separate accounts with separate progression. This doesn't appear to be the case in Smash for Wii U, as I started playing Smash for the first time logged in to the system as my Mii, and it showed all the progression she had unlocked playing under her Mii. How do we keep separate accounts with separate progression?

Comment: As a side note, I think it will actually help you in the long run that your progress is combined. Smash has way too much stuff to unlock, and it's hard enough to do it once, let alone twice.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, separate Mii progression is unavailable in Super Smash Bros 4. It may be added as a later feature, but for now you will have to suffer through not being able to play separately.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't. All saved data is shared as far as I know.